# Spring Ldap: Lookup dn without throwing exception if it isn't there

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

Using [LdapTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html) in Spring LDAP, I have this code:

```
Object object=null;
try{
    String dn = "cn=readers,ou=groups,dc=mycompany, dc=com";
    object = this.ldapTemplate.lookup(dn);
} catch(final NameNotFoundException e){
    // create Object
}
```

But since I've read my Joshua Bloch I know that exceptions should not be used for control flow. Is there a way to look up a dn to see if it exists without throwing an exception if it doesn't? There must be, but I can't find it. I'm looking for code that works like this (or similar):

```
String dn = "cn=readers,ou=groups,dc=mycompany, dc=com";
Object object=this.ldapTemplate.someMethod(dn);
if(object==null){
    // create Object
}
```

Can anybody help?

BTW: just looking at the JavaDoc won't help. None of the methods that throw `NameNotFoundException` say so in the JavaDocs.

Comment: 'Exceptions should not be used for control flow' is a contradiction in terms. Exceptions *are* a form of flow control. They transfer control from one place to another, taking a value (the exception) with them. What this *originally* meant was that exceptions should nit be used like `goto`s within a method. Like many other principles in IT, it has subsequently been inflated into complete meaninglessness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `lookup()` method is only supposed to be used when you know for certain that the DN exists. This is normally because you've searched for and found a user or group previously, and cached the DN returned from the server.

If you're looking for something that might or might not be there, the right API to use is `ldapTemplate.search()`, with an appropriate filter. This returns a list of results, and in the case where no results are found it returns an empty list rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Much too late to help me, but +1 because it might help the next user who needs this. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this answer doesn't say a single word about performance. According to my benchmarks `ldapTemplate.search()` or `ldapTemplate.findOne()` is about 3-4 times slower than `ldapTemplate.lookup()`

Comment: @nervosol So make up your mind. Are you concerned about performance, which at least is a genuine concern, or about some received notion of code 'purity'?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Spring force you here to use exceptions for flow control (i.e. it's not your fault, it's their decision).

I worked with LdapTemplate few months ago and I couldn't find anything better then catch that exception and evaluate that situation as "User not found".

Comment: Yup, that's what I am currently doing, but due to Spring Exception translation, I get lots of stack traces in the log file and it's really ugly.

Comment: @seanizer: I don't know why spring designers desided to use exceptions so hardly, but if you'll look at Spring Security, you'll see that throwing AuthenticationException is a pretty valid solution when you want to swith to another AuthenticationProvider (from LDAP to LocalDB for example). And if you don't enjoy manipulations with exceptions, then don't even look at Spring WebFlow - there you can find over 9k exceptions thrown during one usual request-response cycle.

Comment: Since there apparently is no real answer, telling me that there isn't one is as good as it gets, I guess. Hence I'll accept this answer.

Comment: One cleaner solutions is to wrap lookup() with a try/catch in a method named `isFound()` for example, and return null or false from that method in case of `NameNotFoundException`. Then use `isFound()` to control the flow